# Why jqXHR.abort() in beforeSend thorws an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to abort ajax call using `beforeSend` if certain condition is true.

As soon as I call `jqXHR.abort()` or `return false`.

I get following error

```
TypeError: $.ajax(...).fail is not a function


.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
```

following is the javascript code

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
                    if (1 === 1) {
                        jqXHR.abort();
                    }
                },
                data: { x:1},
                url: 'echo/json'
            })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    console.log("error"+textStatus)
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log("ajax complete");
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/939xG/

Does anyone know why jqXHR.abort() in beforeSend thorws an error?

or how i can change the code in beforeSend such that I can abort the ajax request without any error.

I am using jquery 1.7.2 and can not upgrade to higher version

Comment: My guess is once you abort it, $.ajax() no longer returns a jqXHR. possibly a bug. If you used the error and success callbacks rather than done/fail, i suspect it would stop the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you abort `$.ajax` in beforeSend, `$.ajax` will return `false` rather than a jqXHR. Avoid it by not aborting in beforeSend, or not using done and fail methods in favor of using success and error options instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/939xG/2/

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        if (1 === 1) {
            jqXHR.abort();
        }
    },
    data: {
        x: 1
    },
    url: 'echo/json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("ajax complete");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        console.log("error" + textStatus)
    }
});
console.log(jqXHR) // false
```

This sounds like a bug to me, but since upgrading jquery isn't an option, i didn't look into that possibility.

Comment: You could try finding the bug and patching it in the file.

Comment: And if you wanted to fix it, here are the changes that took place to fix it: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/395612bb152660226b93f7f096cd0146fc06991e